# How to use rails helper method that takes in an icon as an argument?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a method that gives me star rating. The stars will be from fontawesome's [star](http://fontawesome.io/icon/star/) and [star-half](http://fontawesome.io/icon/star-half/). I created the method below that takes in rating (float. 0.0 to 5.0 in 0.5 increments). Half-star will be `<i class="fa fa-star-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and star will be `<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>`. If rating is 3.5, it is expected to return (3 × `star`) + (1 × `half-star`).

```
def star_rating(rating, star, half_star)
  star = star
  half_star = half_star
  if ((rating % 1).round == 1) #ends with 0.5
    result = (rating - 0.5).round * star + half_star
  else
    result = rating * star
  end
  return result
end
```

I have never done something like this before. My initial thought was to put the `star_rating()` inside Ruby helper (`posts_helper.rb` in this case).

In post's view `index.html.erb`, I did `<%= star_rating(post.rating, <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>, <i class="fa fa-star-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>) %>` but it threw an error.

In short, I have a ruby method that takes a value from model (`post.rating`) and two icons (`fa-star` and `fa-star-half`). What is the best practice to use ruby method in conjunction with fontawesome's icons to achieve intended star rating?

I am aware there are several gems to do this, but I am trying to make it from scratch to help me understand rails more.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to able to pass `star` and `half_star` as arguments? Will those arguments ever be different from the above?

Comment: Yes, they are part of the original design. The arguments themselves can be changed, but the input/ output will need to be (rating) -> (function) -> (display of stars and half stars depending on rating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really not sure if it's right way showing rating trough helper.
But this should work:

create partial file

```
# _rating.html.erb
<%= fa_icon "#{icon_name}" %>
```

add to your required view file

```
# view.html.erb
<%= show_raiting(3.3) %>
```

and add method to helper, where `path/to/your` it's path to _rating.html.erb template

```
#***_helper.rb
def show_raiting(rating)
    rating = rating.to_f
    if rating.present?
      output_stars = ''
      rating.floor.times do
        output_stars += render partial: 'path/to/your/rating', locals: { icon_name: 'star' }
      end
      output_stars += render partial: 'path/to/your/rating', locals: { icon_name: 'star-half' } unless rating % 1 == 0
      output_stars.html_safe
    end
end
```